# Mapstruct: ignored MapperConfig

Tags: mapstruct

I've two `MapperConfig`:

```java
@MapperConfig(
    uses = {
        StringTypeMapper.class,
        ExtensionMapper.class
    }
)
public interface ElementMapperConfig extends GenericMapperConfig {
    
    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "idElement")
    @Mapping(target = "extension", source = "extension")
    Element mapElement(org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.Element fhir);

}
```

And `GenericMapperConfig`:

```java
@MapperConfig(
    componentModel = "spring",
    injectionStrategy = InjectionStrategy.CONSTRUCTOR,
    nullValueCheckStrategy = NullValueCheckStrategy.ALWAYS,
    nullValueMappingStrategy = NullValueMappingStrategy.RETURN_NULL
)
public interface GenericMapperConfig {

}
```

As you can see, I'm using `spring` component model.

Nevertheless, Mapper implementation is getting required Mapper using `Mappers.getMapper(...)`.

As you can see, `ElementMapperConfig` extends `GenericMapperConfig`, but it seems that configuration from `GenericMapperConfig` is ignored.

Generated Mapper example:

```java
@Generated(
    value = "org.mapstruct.ap.MappingProcessor"
)
public class StringTypeMapperImpl implements StringTypeMapper {

    private final ExtensionMapper extensionMapper = Mappers.getMapper( ExtensionMapper.class );

}
```

`StringTypeMapper`  is:

```java
@Mapper(
    config = ElementMapperConfig.class
)
public interface StringTypeMapper {

    @InheritConfiguration(name = "mapElement")
    StringType fhirToMpi(org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.StringType stringType);

}
```

I don't quite figure out why `GenericMapperConfig` configuration is not populated, I mean, I don't get why `componentModel = "spring"` is ignored on `Mapper` implementation.

Answer (score 3):

The documentation does not mention this way of composing multiple `MapperConfiguration`s.

It also does not mention another way of doing it, but this one works. The idea is to extend mappers instead of configurations.

Introduce a base mapper with generic configuration:

```java
@Mapper(
    config = GenericMapperConfig.class
)
public interface BaseMapper {
}
```

Base your concrete mapper on the base one and configure it using the specific configuration:

```java
@Mapper(
    config = ElementMapperConfig.class
)
public interface StringTypeMapper extends BaseMapper {
    @InheritConfiguration(name = "mapElement")
    StringType fhirToMpi(org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.StringType stringType);
}
```

Finally make ElementMapperConfig not inherit GenericMapperConfig:

```java
@MapperConfig(
    uses = {
        StringTypeMapper.class,
        ExtensionMapper.class
    }
)
public interface ElementMapperConfig {
    @Mapping(target = "id", source = "idElement")
    @Mapping(target = "extension", source = "extension")
    Element mapElement(org.hl7.fhir.r4.model.Element fhir);
}
```

Comment: Interesting to see this working. It has not been documented because we have never thought about it, and it could be that it works by accident. In any case it is indeed a solution to the current problem.